# Excel chart adapting to table with formula-generated rows -- without named ranges?

Tags: excel, charts, excel-formula

I have table-like data, and I'm looking to make a chart that displays that data. Since the data is that formula-generated from other data in the workbook, I don't know in advance how many lines it will have. I want to make a chart that adapts to this data.

Up to this part of the question, I could use [named ranges](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/defined-names-to-update-chart-range) to solve this.

The thing with the solution with named ranges is that it does not scale well when I have many of these charts. I have a Python script that generates CSV files that I import into my workbook as a sheet, and I don't want to have to know in advance how many of them there will be, or what they will be named. I only want to be able to import the CSV files into a new or existing sheet, and copy-paste the formulas from another working sheet, as well as be able to replace the existing CSV data with new data.

With named ranges, I would have to manually create a named range for each series of each sheet, and I would have to use the sheet's name so that the named range can be visible to the whole workbook (in order to analyze the data in a global sheet) without any name conflict. This is (more or less) acceptable when I do these steps myself now, but if I want to redo this in a few months, or if I pass my workbook to someone else, we wouldn't know why it's not working with a new sheet.

So is there any way to get this done without delving into VBA stuff? I'm using a recent version of Excel.

Comment: Tough for me to envision your process, so not sure if this suggestion makes sense, but could you create your charts from pivot tables? That is, create a pivot from the formula-based results (using far more rows than you would ever expect), exclude your "blank" rows in the pivot filter and generate the chart from that? Would just need to refresh your pivot each time. Again, may not make sense but I cannot understand the flow here.

Comment: @Isolated Thanks for your suggestion. I didn't read about pivot tables while I was searching for a solution.  I tried it and it indeed seems to solve my problem. The only thing we'll have to remember is to update the pivot table when we update the data, but at this point it's just nitpicking. If you write an answer with your suggestion, I'll accept it.

Comment: glad it works for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the comments, try using pivot tables, making your range extend far beyond expected results and filtering out "blanks" in your pivot and generate your chart from that. The default pivot chart is ugly but you can remove buttons and format as needed. Just remember to refresh your pivot during every update period.